# Solr - How to make several searches on a single query?

Tags: apache, search, solr, lucene, search-engine

I'm trying to make a query that:

- First try to match strings, just lowercase processing, and generate a score, boost x
- Second, try to use the 'text_en' processing and generate a score, boost y
- Trird, Use 'text_en' with synonyms, and generate a score, boost z

Is this possible?
I made the following configuration but I don't think it's doing what I described... It works but I don't trust on the results.

solrconfig.xml:

```
  <requestHandler name="/querystems" class="solr.SearchHandler">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
      <str name="wt">json</str>
      <str name="indent">true</str>
      <str name="qf">
         lowercase^2 title_without_synonym description_without_synonym title_stems^1.5 description_stems^1
      </str>
      <str name="q.alt">*:*</str>
      <str name="rows">100</str>
      <str name="fl">id,title,description,reuseCount,score,title_stems,description_stems</str>
      <str name="defType">edismax</str>
    </lst>
  </requestHandler>
```

schema.xml:

```
  <field name="title" type="text_en_test" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <field name="title_without_synonym" type="text_en_without_synonym" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <field name="title_stems" type="text_en_stems" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <copyField source="title" dest="title_without_synonym" maxChars="30000" />
  <copyField source="title" dest="title_stems" maxChars="30000" />

  <field name="description" type="text_en_test" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <field name="description_without_synonym" type="text_en_without_synonym" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <field name="description_stems" type="text_en_stems" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <copyField source="description" dest="description_without_synonym" maxChars="30000" />
  <copyField source="description" dest="description_stems" maxChars="30000" />
```

I don't even know why that 'lowercase' field works at the query configuration, as it's a 'fieldType', not 'field'... Can someone help me undestanding and better configurating this scenario?

Comment: So what isn't working? Your general setup seems OK, but you probably want to boost hits without synonyms more - use `debugQuery` to see how much each field is contributing to the score. The "lowercase" field may match a wildcard (for example, many schemas define a "*" match as ignored, or for creating fields in a schemaless configuration), or have been used earlier.

Comment: @MatsLindh I'm using debugQuery to better understanting and at any case I see the 'lowercase' boost... why? Anyway, so if I want to add several preprocessing types with different boosts I can just use what I did above?

Comment: Yes. Exactly what isn't working with your current setup?

Comment: @MatsLindh If I just add the title_text_general, for example, on the "qf" tag of the query, it results 0.... And that 'lowercase' is a strange case because even if I comment the "<copyField source="*" dest="_text_"/>" it continue working...

Comment: The thing is that it's actually generating results, but I think I cannot trust it because I'm not sure what this configuration really do

Comment: I'm not sure what removing a copyField that doesn't reference the field as a destination would do. But `debugQuery` is the way to go to see why a document was ranked as it was (it'll show the weights generated by each field).

Comment: I used this and a very strange thing that happens is that the 'lowercase field' doesn't appears on the debbug, but it does indeed affect the query. I simply don't know what's happening. I can show you the debbug query. I will pastebin it.

Comment: Check this log: https://pastebin.com/wtT4GmaY

Comment: How does it affect the query? There is no score contributed from that field according to your debugQuery output.

Comment: Exactly. There's no score attributed but the retrieved documents are very different (more precise retrieval than when there's no 'lowercase' field). Do you think I have to report this 'issue'?